# Necessary and sufficient condition for global minima in convex optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

> Minimize $f(x)$ subject to $x \in C$, $C$ is convex set

> Necessary and sufficient condition for $\bar x$ to be global minima of the above problem is $<\nabla f(\bar x), x- \bar x> \geq 0 $    $\forall x \in C$

proof in textbook:

$ x \in C, \bar x, \implies \bar x + \lambda (x- \bar x) \in C \forall \lambda \in (0,1) \\ f(\bar x + \lambda (x- \bar x)) \geq f(\bar x) \\ $  **[what if global min is not in C? as showin below in diagram]**

by taylors expansion we get

$<\nabla f(\bar x), x- \bar x> \geq 0 $    $\forall x \in C$

It also looks intuitive when i think as below

BUt what if $\bar x$ is not in C ie., when i consider C not containing global min then $\bar x + \lambda (x- \bar x) $ may not be in C right?

[image]

Comment: If you consider a constrained problem, you also deal with a constrained global minimizer. I.e., $\bar x \in C$ attains the smallest functional value on $C$ (and not on the entire space).

Comment: understood now sir... thank you